# What does vim ` char mean?

Tags: vim

I am looking around to try and understand a line of code via latest snipMate plugin source.

The statement appears at the autoload section of the plugin

```
for expr in s:snippet_filenames(scope,escape(a:trigger, "*[]?{}`'$|#%"))
     for path in g:snipMate.snippet_dirs
           for file in s:Glob(path, expr)
                source `=file`    <-----
           endfor
     endfor
endfor
```

The above code iterates over all files found in the snippet folder and executes the `source` statement - but what exactly does it do? what does `=file` means?

Comment: `soruce`? Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: you're correct, just a typo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `` :help `= ``. Basically, it will evaluate `file` as a VimL expression, then insert the result into the command line. E.g. `` echo `="file" . "name"` `` will expand to `echo filename`, and will print the value of the variable `filename`.

In your case, for example, if `file` is `ticks.txt`, `` source `=file` `` will execute `source ticks.txt`.